# How to store data in a .NET Core 2.1 WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm developing a WebApi in .NET Core 2.1 and I need to have a shared key/value storage that can be written and read by any request received by the API.

The storage should use the application's heap and not external systems (for example a Redis cache or a flat file solution) since I have to keep C# objects which I can't serialize.

Comment: Please note that in memory storage is not persistent. Having said that: you can use `statics`, but make sure they are thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you want to store your data in c#, like memory cache. 
You can use the class below.

```
 public class ApplicationCacheManager
        {
            private Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }

            public ApplicationCacheManager()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }

            public bool IsSet(string key)
            {
                return Data.TryGetValue(key, out var data) && data != null;
            }

            public T Get<T>(string key)
            {
                if (Data.TryGetValue(key, out var data))
                    return (T)data;

                return default(T);
            }

            public void Set<T>(string key, T data)
            {
                Data[key] = data;
            }

            public void Remove(string key)
            {
                Data.Remove(key);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (Data != null)
                    Data = null;
            }
        }
```

This class should be singleton to store all data along application lifetime.
register it to DI container as singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<ApplicationCacheManager>();
```

If you want this class to be thread safe, You can change Dictinary to ConcurrentDictionary. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I just finished to implement it and it works like a charm.

Comment: glad to help, enjoy!